# Split Strings from an array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, split

I want to extract lines from an array of strings, and split the ";" separator while stocking datas in an array. I know this is what the split method is supposed to do. But I can't get through. 
How should I process ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String LON = in.next();
        String LAT = in.next();
        int N = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        String[] infoDefib=new String[N];                                  
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String DEFIB = in.nextLine();
            infoDefib[i]=DEFIB.split(";");
        }
        //System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split function will split the String and store each of them into a String array.

ex: String[] strs = DEFIB.split(";");

You don't have to use a for loop and store them into String[] separately. New a String[] and equal to String.split("***"). Java will do it for you.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String LON = in.next();
    //String LAT = in.next();        
    String str = in.nextLine(); // use nextLine which you can read whole 
                                //line and store the data into a String
    in.nextLine();
    String[] infoDefib = DEFIB.split(";");//now you store them into a String array
```

Comment: The problem when I declare and initialize the array in the for loop, is that I don't know how to get it back outside of the loop. I'm a newbie in Java.

Answer (score 1):

String's **`split()`** method is pretty straight forward. You need to pass delimiter as an argument and it will return an array of string having string separated by provided delimiter.

***Example :***

```
String data = "This.is.simple.example.of.split.method";
String[] splitArray = data.split(".");//period(.) being delimeter
for (String val : splitArray) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

***Result :***

```
This
is
simple
example
of
split
method
```